# How to get all selected values of Tag Picker in Fluent UI

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

In [the docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/pickers), some of the props do not exist on the component, so I guess it's outdated.

I have a TagPicker component, I'm using the Tag Picker with inline suggestions one.

```
<TagPicker
    onResolveSuggestions={filterSuggestedTags}
    getTextFromItem={getTextFromItem}
    pickerSuggestionsProps={{
      suggestionsHeaderText: 'Tags',
      noResultsFoundText: 'No tags found',
    }}
    pickerCalloutProps={{ doNotLayer: true }}
    inputProps={inputProps}
  />
```

And I want its value to be stored in a state (as an array of strings).
I tried to find events of selecting and removing but couldn't find them.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onChange` event for add/remove items and `selectedItems` for component state.

```js
// Import ITag interface from FluentUI.
const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState<ITag[]>([])

<TagPicker
  ...
  onChange={items => items && setSelectedItems(items)}
  selectedItems={selectedItems}
/>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/YzeyvEm?editors=0011) working example.